# Word or Phrase for the small protuberance found opposite the handle on a tea strainer?

Tags: single-word-requests

As seen in the following images :

Here: [Link](http://us.123rf.com/450wm/firstblood/firstblood1307/firstblood130701056/20735170-metallic-tea-strainer-with-red-handle-isolated-on-white-background.jpg)

The bumpy thing aiding the strainer in hanging on to a teacup here: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_strainer#mediaviewer/File%3aTeacup&Strainer.JPG)

Does this part of the anatomy of a tea strainer (and other similar items which need to hang from the lips of larger items) actually have a name by which it can be referred?

Comment: I don't think there's any specific name, but you could call it an *ear, lug, handle, projection, support, ledge, hook* etc. Or just a ["sticky-out thingy"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sticky-out+thingy%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22sticky-out+thingy%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.23357798j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) (I cite 2790 instances of that rather awkward phrase as evidence we don't have an exact word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *[lug](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lug#Noun)* (with sense “A part of something which sticks out, used as a handle or support”) has been used for that part.  For example, here is part of an [auction-site description](http://www.bryandouglas.co.uk/silverware/tea_strainers_infusers/tea_strainers_infusers.htm) for the item pictured below:

> Sterling silver tea strainer and bowl, having a handle with reeded border, hand-pierced bowl with two pierced **lugs**, and sitting on a raised bowl on square base. ...

[image: Sterling silver tea strainer and bowl, item #j9265]

Comment: Yeah - I'm not a design engineer, but my guess is that's what they'd normally call such protuberances (in this case, supporting against gravity, but in many other cases, ***locating** lugs*.

Answer (score 0):

The *rest* is the little cup into which you put the whole strainer after use so it does not drip on anything else. The part you have in mind appears, from Web advertisements for strainers and sieves, to be most often termed a *hook,* even when it is not curved downward for a firmer grip on the edge of the vessel into which you are straining material. Whether it is still called that when it is a mere half-disk of sheet metal as in your second linked image, and not a loop of rim wire as in the first, I do not know. OED s.v. *hook* is unhelpful here.